# Pandas dataframe.to_csv() returns each row in quotes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've got a Python script that writes a Pandas dataframe to a CSV file for
visualization. The script calls the .to_csv() method, but each row of the
resulting CSV is in quotes, which prevents the rest of my script from returning
the correct output. This dataframe:

```
    source, target, value
0  Foxtrot, Uniform, 1000
1        Golf, Alpha, 500
2        Zulu, India, 120
3   Uniform, Foxtrot, 100
```

is written to a CSV as:

```
"source, target, value"
"Foxtrot, Uniform, 1000"
"Golf, Alpha, 500"
"Zulu, India, 120"
"Uniform, Foxtrot, 100"
```

I've tried several different kwargs for the .to_csv method, to no avail. Anyone
have a fix?

Comment: Can you paste the exact output you get from the Python interpreter if you call `.to_csv(None)` so that it prints the result as a string. If the individual lines are not quote-delimited in that output (i.e. the only quotes are at the beginning and end, given that your data doesn't have quotes in the string columns) then I suspect this is just a display issue. Have you tried reading the resulting csv with another module, like standard `csv` to see if the file format is as expected by another library?

Comment: That looks a lot more like you have a DataFrame with only column, not three, and pandas is (correctly!) quoting the output to remove the ambiguity.  While not impossible, it seems unlikely that's what you intended.  You could edit the question to include the output from `df.info()`, which would clarify the situation.

Comment: I ask because I cannot reproduce this error. This is not what Pandas does, so something else is going on.

Comment: Good catch @DSM -- it could be a single column with a long string for a name, and long strings for the values. The tab alignment makes it seem like that's likely.

Comment: The problem was with how the dataframe was read, rather than with the way the CSV was written! I forgot to specify a comma as a delimiter in .read_table(). This is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas .read_table() needs to have the correct delimiter specified, else it returns a single long string for each row. .to_csv() returns the correct (unquoted) output if the dataframe is correctly formatted.